# write number on several digits

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I think that I don't understant `ToString()` method correctly. How to get number on 3 digits?

12 as 012
123 as 123
6 as 006

```
i.ToString("000");
```

results in 6 as 600.

Comment: `PadLeft` with '0', this should do the trick. Documentation is available here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Use String.format, http://www.dotnetperls.com/format

Comment: If i is 6, i.ToString("000") gave 006 when I tested.

Comment: Use d. then you don't need to write to many zeros.

Comment: @Adil Point for you, but I have no idea why. I've used d3 from below, getting error ("wrong format"), and then switched back to 000. Works now, but I still wonder what was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `d`. For example: `ToString("d3");`

Answer (score 0):

```
i.PadLeft(3,'0');
```

More info on `PadLeft` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx